# How to purge logstash

Tags: apt, dpkg, purge

I need to purge logstash but as I try to run apt purge logstash I get an error:

```
root@vmi503579:~# apt purge logstash
^Citing for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock. It is held by process 2797938 (dpkg)... 20s
```

So I tried to find pid 2797938 which results in this

```
root@vmi503579:~# ps -x | grep 2797938
2797938 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 57 --no-triggers --force-depends --abort-after=1 --remove logstash:amd64
```

It was my previous attempt to stop logstash. So I try to kill process 2797938 and run purge logstash again. No success. Then I tried to kill all processes with keyword logstash.
Then try to run apt purge logstash again

```
root@vmi503579:~# apt purge logstash
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Now I am really lost. What should I do to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow error messages shown.

Use commands below:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And then remove `logstash` package by

```
sudo apt-get purge logstash
```

Comment: Hi, what is `apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: Ok -f means fix, But how much time can spend `apt purge logstash` command? I am waiting few minutes without any result.

Comment: Now one hour without any result. :(

Comment: In join with this thread https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-not-purge-logstash/277225/3 I was able to remove the Logstash. Thanks you very much